# exclude non-representative points from jmeter results / log

Tags: jmeter

When you implement a step-up Load scenario using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/).. there are certain key representative points (concurrent threads) that you are interested in.

For example 17, 33, 50, 67, 83, 100 are the representative points with this scenario... [image]

In-addition to these representative points it generates requests with 99,98..3,2,1 concurrent threads.

1. I haven't found a way to configure this plugin to not generate the step-down threads
2. Let us say there is no way to do it, is there way to exclude the non-representative thread counts from the final JTL / CSV results summary?

These representative points add too much noise to the final graphs and tend to confuse folks higher up the food chain. There are options on certain graph plug-ins on the GUI mode that allow you to hide the noise. Is there any option to exclude these from the log file so my graph on the HTML dash board looks clean without the noise?

With Noise:
[Final Results CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hpRYzoJ-hw0cE_7jlufpikLqadMSWXbB/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Without Noise:
[Final Results CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mD7joK4n1AbRe2EaKo6SdkxJDIzdfiT6/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Here is the graph on the HTML Dashboard report without the noise (I manually edited the JS to remove the non-rep points):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once sampler has occurred it will be captured by listeners and written, I cannot think of an easy way to prevent this behaviour, only of something like adding timestamp to the sampler name in the runtime, discarding results which have timestamp more than defined value and removing the timestamp for reports consistency, this can be done via [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) scripting.

1. There are the following [HTML Report Generator properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general):

   - `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date`

     > Start date of the range of data to use for report.
     >   Date format is defined by date_format property.
     >   Default: not filled which means data range will be used from the beginning
   - `jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date`

     > End date of the range of data to use for report.
     >   Date format is defined by date_format property.
     >   Default: not filled which means data range will be used until the end

   So you basically need to set `jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date` property to some timestamp before tear down starts
2. There is [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which can "cut" your original .jtl results file according to specified `start-offset` and `end-offset` parameters. You can install the tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thank you for the response and inputs. I will try this. Is there any way to configure the Concurrency Thread Group to not generate the step-down thread counts? Hold target Rate field is tied into the formula and cannot set it to maintain the full load through the entire duration of the test.